# ¿por que no me reemplaza el div?

Tags: javascript, html

Megutaria saber por que no puedo reemplazar el div.

ya que cuando lo preciono solo puedo reemplazar 3.
mi codigo es este:

```
<div class="l_power1" id="l_power1" onclick="boton1()"></div>
<div class="r_power2" id="r_power2" onclick="boton2()"></div>
<div class="r_power3" id="r_power3" onclick="boton3()"></div>
<div class="l_power4" id="l_power4" onclick="boton4()"></div>
```

y los quiero reemplazar por estos otros.

```
introducir el código aquí
<div class="1_power1c" id="l_power1c" onclick="" ></div>
<div class="r_power2c" id="r_power2c" onclick="stop()"></div>
<div class="r_power3c" id="r_power3c" onclick="start()"></div>
<div class="l_power4c" id="l_power4c" onclick="reset()"></div>
```

pero no logro reemplazar el div

> div class="l_power1" id="l_power1" onclick="boton1()">

mi js

```
function cambiaVisibilidad1() {
   var div1 = document.getElementById('clock');
    var div2 = document.getElementById('clock2');
    var div3 = document.getElementById('l_power1c');
    var div4 = document.getElementById('l_power1');
    if(div2.style.display === 'block'){        
        div2.style.display = 'none';
        div1.style.display = 'block';
        div3.style.display = 'none';
        div4.style.display ='block'; 

    }else{
       div2.style.display = 'block';
       div1.style.display = 'none';
    }


    $('.r_power2').on('click').fadeToggle(); 
    $('.r_power3').on('click').fadeToggle();
    $('.l_power4').on('click').fadeToggle();
}
```

que estare haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Dónde intentas reemplazar?

Comment: Estás usando **1** en vez de **l** en la clase `1_power1c`